# Azure function Isolated worker - host vs worker logging config

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

In the docs for the isolated worker model, it says you have to configure logging for the worker and the host separately:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#managing-log-levels

> The Functions host and the isolated process worker have separate
> configuration for log levels, etc. Any Application Insights
> configuration in host.json will not affect the logging from the
> worker, and similarly, configuration made in your worker code will not
> impact logging from the host. You need to apply changes in both places
> if your scenario requires customization at both layers.

That's fine, but it's unclear which logs are emitted by the host vs the worker. For example, if I'm trying to set log level for Azure.Core so that it only logs Errors, do I set that in host.json or the appsettings for my worker, or both?

Answer (score 0):

> to set log level for Azure.Core so that it only logs Errors, do I set that in host.json or the appsettings for my worker, or both?

The configuration file of `worker process is appsettings.json` in that to set the logging level for specific components or libraries used within the functions code. to set the logging level for the Azure.Core namespace in the worker's like below:

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Azure.Core": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

- By this configuration `Azure.Core` namespace logs only the Error logs. `not necessary to set the same config also in host.json`.

For Azure function host set the logging levels in `host.json` file. To set the host logging level like below:

**Host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

The above configuration will ensure that the host emits logs at the "Information" level.
I have refered this [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1415) for the isolated logging levels for function.

Comment: I suppressed Azure.Core errors in my host.json instead of appsettings.json and it worked, which tells me those particular logs were coming from the host, not the worker, but it was just a lucky guess. It would be nice if the source was provided in the log metadata.