# Azure Function Isolated Worker: Is it possible to write the host logs to the console provider?

Tags: logging, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated, dotnet-isolated

For a .net 6 isolated worker app these are the logs of an initial run and in here we can see that there are no console provider entries for the 'Executing' and 'Executed' messages, they don't have the 'info:'.
[image]

My goal is to have these messages printed like in the image below in which an azure function in-process .net6 app is writing the logs as expected, with the 'info:'.
[image]

This is the .net 6 isolated worker code used to print the logs of the first image:

`Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, lb) => {
        lb.AddConsole();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

`local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

`host.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

`.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here we have the .net 6 in-process function code used to print the logs on the second image:

`Startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(WorkerLogsToSerilogInProcess.Startup))]
namespace WorkerLogsToSerilogInProcess
{
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddConsole());
        }
    }
}
```

`local.settings.json`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

`host.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In addition to the current code of the isolated function, I've also tried to set the logging:logLevel:default to Information on both the host.json and local.settings.json without success. Reference: [Azure function Isolated worker - host vs worker logging config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083244/azure-function-isolated-worker-host-vs-worker-logging-config)

So, is it possible to write the function runtime logs on the console provider when using an isolated worker azure function?

Comment: Try with this **host.json** in your code :- 
**{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "console": {
            "category": "Function",
            "logLevel": {
                "default": "Information"
            }
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}**

Comment: @DasariKamali
No success in updating the host.json as you suggested.

Comment: Hi @mathro, I'm not getting the logs like you're getting even I tried with your given in-process code. Actually, why would you add program.cs to in-process azure functions project? I know that program.cs comes by default in isolated worker process but not in in-process of .NET.

Comment: Hi @JashuaCriss, the program.cs is for the isolated process, it is right below "This is the .net 6 isolated worker code used to print the logs of the first image...". And there is another section for the in-process that uses a startup.cs.

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried to get the host level logs to the console as you shown with the below process**:
*Below is the .NET 6 Isolated Azure Function App Project Code*:

**.csproj code**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Program.cs**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Here I received the console logs including the host-information level as expected but the executing statement is not repeated twice like in your screenshot provided:

**For this configuration of host.json**:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "Function.Function1": "Information",
        "default": "Information"
      },
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        },

        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

**For this configuration of host.json**:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "Function.Function1": "Debug",
        "default": "Debug"
      },
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        },

        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

Make sure all of my above code files should be same to get the same host level logs to the console.

*Reference: [MS Doc of Azure functions Host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)*

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but this is still not what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm not expressing myself properly, but if you take a look at the "Executed..." and "Executing..." logs of the In-process function model on the original post, we can notice that there is a "info: " in front of these logs. And this is what I understand as the host logs been written to the console provider.

Comment: @mathro Yes! In your .net in process Azure function project, you have used `WorkerLogsToSerilogInProcess` which is a open-source logging framework that supports structured logging so that the application is generating the structured logs in the form of information.

Whereas your .net isolated process Azure function doesn't contain the method of `WorkerLogsToSerilogInProcess` related code so the application is not generating the informative logs from the application.

Comment: This is incorrect. Serilog is not being inject on both the isolated or in-process flows presented on the original post. If you check the program.cs of the isolated process or the  startup.cs of the in-process flow, you will see that just a framework native console is being added.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying `Program.cs` to be like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services
            .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()
            .ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights()
            .AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders(); // Removes the default console logger
                logging.AddApplicationInsights();
                logging.AddSimpleConsole(c => // Adds a new console logger
                {
                    c.SingleLine = true; // Ensures the "info" etc is at the start of the line.
                });
            });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

My thinking is:

- The default console logger is set up for "multi-line" output. This makes it look like it's dropping the `info` etc. (but in practice, it's just splitting it over multiple lines.)
- By calling `.ClearProviders()` we're removing that default multi-line logger.
- We then add a single line logger back in.

I don't have an Application Insights resource available at the moment, so I haven't tested whether it still remains enabled after the `.ClearProviders()`. So do check that still works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work.
I believe this might be something intrinsic to the Isolated worker process rather than something related to formatting.
From my understading, these 'function runtime' logs are not going through the console provider.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Thanks for trying anyway. For what it's worth, the above does work for me, albeit I'm testing locally with the output going to the Terminal pane in VSCode. Maybe there's something in the environment?